# How to make that when I press space it does an action in my CLI in dart

Tags: dart, command-line-interface, keyevent

I am creating a dart cli that allows to display one or more colors at random but what I would like to do is that when we press the "space" key it displays a new color.

Code in nodeJS that I want to reproduce in dart. Here the module used is [Terminal-kit](https://github.com/cronvel/terminal-kit)

```js
term.grabInput(true)
function checkKeyPress(name) {
    //Si la touche espace est appuyée, on relance le programme
    if (name === ' ') {
        term.grabInput(false)
        term.removeListener('key', checkKeyPress)
        //Faire attendre 0.1 secondes
        setTimeout(() => {
            colornew()
        }, 80)
    }

    if (name === 'ESCAPE') {
        term.grabInput(false)
        term.removeListener('key', checkKeyPress)
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.clear()
            process.stdout.write('\x1Bc');
            return main()
        }, 80)
    }
}
term.addListener('key', checkKeyPress)
}
colornew()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by disabling `lineMode` on `stdin` which makes it so your terminal are sending data to your data program right away instead of waiting for the next line.

I would also recommend disabling `echoMode` so you can't see the `space` in the terminal.

So something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

final int spaceChar = ' '.codeUnitAt(0);

void main() async {
  stdin.echoMode = false;
  stdin.lineMode = false;

  await for (final event in stdin) {
    if (event.first == spaceChar) {
      print('SPACE!!!!!');
    }
  }
}
```